# How to use Webview2.Effect

Tags: c#, wpf, shader, effect, webview2

BACKGROUND: We are using light projectors to display our application. Light projectors can be used just like displays. Projectors, however induce distortions that are corrected using geometric warping. We create shaders using the Shader properties provided on the UIElement class in WPF to do the geometric corrective warping. We have a handle on all that.

PROBLEM: All UIElement visuals are properly corrected on the projector screen -- except on the WebView2 UIElement. I have come to the conclusion that the Effect property of the WebView2 class doesn't work.

**THIS WORKS: (No Webview2)**

```
 <Grid>   
        <Rectangle  x:Name="Grid0" Height="800" Width="1280">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <ImageBrush x:Name="ProjectorLut" />
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        
        </Rectangle>

        <Canvas Height="800" Width="1280" >
      
            <Image ImageSource="BoundToRenderBitmpapSource"  Height="800" Width="1280"/>
 
            <Canvas.Effect>
                <local:CalibrationEffect>
                    <local:CalibrationEffect.Input2>
                        <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=Grid0}" />
                    </local:CalibrationEffect.Input2>
                </local:CalibrationEffect>
            </Canvas.Effect>
      </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

**THIS DOESN'T WORK**

```
 <Grid>   
        <Rectangle  x:Name="Grid0" Height="800" Width="1280">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <ImageBrush x:Name="ProjectorLut" />
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
        <Canvas Height="800" Width="1280" >
      
            <wv2:WebView2 Name="webView"  Source="https://earth.google.com" Height="800" Width="1280" >
            </wv2:WebView2>
           
            <Canvas.Effect>
                <local:CalibrationEffect>
                    <local:CalibrationEffect.Input2>
                        <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=Grid0}" />
                    </local:CalibrationEffect.Input2>
                </local:CalibrationEffect>
            </Canvas.Effect>
     </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

So I tried something different. I replaced the XAML code for WebView2 with an image class bound to a RenderTargetBitmap generated imagesource rendered by creating the RenderTargetBitmap imagesource in code behind. That doesn't work for me either.

QUESTION: How can I look at this problem differently or am I doing something I need to look at more deeply?

I am using Desptop WPF and I appreciate your help.

Comment: WW2 renders its content directly to the screen using a dedicated rectangle to it. In other words, Canvas isn't aware of contents inside that rectangle. Possible solution is WW2 render redirect to some other output and apply filter to that output, and display the filtered video. But fast filtering video stream is not a simple thing. So, here's some tasks to do: 1) capture the WW2 output 2) apply filter to the each frame 3) disply the result video. *Btw, there's another easier way to apply the filter.* Do it with JavaScript directly in the WW2 page. WebView can execute JS scripts.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did try to "redirect" by using RenderTargetBitmap to a virtual BitmapImage and by binding that to an XAML Image element, with an Effect of the shader needed. It did not work, even though that pattern worked in scenarios not employing WebView2. If you know of an alternative for RenderTargetBitmap -- please let me know. Also note, I am exploring the JS option. It appears there are shaders available for JS -- and that appears encouraging.